# Finding Supply/Nominal voltage for Torque Motor BLDC

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, electrical, electric-vehicles

I'm a bit confused by torque motors datasheets as it never mentions any nominal voltage. I would like to run a torque motor on a 24 V battery.

The required max torque is 150 Nm (=21000 oz-in) and max speed 15 RPM. (=1.57 rad/s). I have found a motor that shows max torque, max current at this torque but I don't find any nominal voltage.

If I multiply $K_e$ (V/rad.s^-1) by max speed and add the voltage drop in the resistor ($R*I_{max}$), I can find 132 V.

1. Why does the torque motor not have a nominal voltage? (compared to the classical BLDC motors)
2. Are the supply voltage calculations (132 V) correct?
3. In this case, should I choose a boost converter (24 VDC -> +132 VDC?) followed by a motor drive that can handle this voltage?

You can find the motor datasheet below.

[image: Datasheet of a motor that may fit my requirements]